# Java - Instance variable is dependent on Constructor argument

Tags: java, constructor

I want to set a variable which is dependent on the argument passed to the constructor.
At the moment my code looks something like this. Is calling a method here bad practice and is there a better way of doing this? I have searched for an answer but haven't been able to find anything. All help appreciated.

```
public class Test {
    int num;

    public Test(int num) {
        this.num = prime(num);
    }

    public int prime(int num) {
        //code to get a prime number
    }   
}
```

Comment: You should write class names with a capital Letter.

Comment: Yeah I know cheers

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method from constructor is bad practice if it is an overridable method. 
With overridable methods you get into initialisation order troubles. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors).

You should make your `prime()` method private, static or final.

Comment: I never thought of that, but it is right, of course.

Comment: Or make the method `final`.

Comment: The key element why static is better than private or final: a static method can't ever use any of the fields of that class. This you avoid all the potential issues from accessing non static fields prior those being initialized!

Comment: Yeah that was the original way I did it